# Style a specific X-axis label with ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I see in the ChartJS docs (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) how to style the x-axis as a whole, but I'd like to style a single label.

I have an example codepen here https://codepen.io/jsilver951/pen/pozOBzy?editors=1000 where I've tried to add the attribute in before the update function but nothing is working.

Incorrect

`lineChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontColor = "hsl(0,100%,50%)";`

Does anyone know how or even if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

This issue of changing the style of each tick was raised here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442.
A working solution was created by @bevingtongroup[1](https://github.com/bevingtongroup/Chart.js) with an example of how to use it by @kneeki here[2](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-360866070). 
The issue is now closed but I'm not sure if its fully implemented into the latest chart.js version. Hope this helps solve your issue!

Comment: Looks like it's available on the dev version, but not the latest stable version unfortunately